# Multi-dimensional array to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to print my data and encode it into JSON. I'm extracting the data from my MySQL database for a quiz. The data that I am trying to extract 1 question, 1 category and 4 options to make a set of quiz. I think I nearly got it how to make it work but I failed to find out how. This was the result check in this [link](http://mbcatubig.net16.net/ExQuiz%20Me/Quiz_Manager.php).
Paste the JSON to this [link](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) so that you can easily format it. From that JSON data, I want to output like this for each question:

```
      "What is the approximate number of islands that comprise the Philippines?",
      "Philippine Geography",
      [  
         {  
            "quiz_choice_id":"5",
            "choice":"7000",
            "is_correct_choice":"1"
         },
         {  
            "quiz_choice_id":"6",
            "choice":"6000",
            "is_correct_choice":"0"
         },
         {  
            "quiz_choice_id":"7",
            "choice":"8000",
            "is_correct_choice":"0"
         },
         {  
            "quiz_choice_id":"8",
            "choice":"9000",
            "is_correct_choice":"0"
         }
      ],
```

This is my code for that:

```
 <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Muhammad
 * Date: 19/04/2016
 * Time: 00:46
 */
require_once('Database_Connect.php');

$questions_query = "SELECT question, quiz_choice_id, choice ,is_correct_choice, category FROM category_question cq, question q, question_choices qc WHERE q.quiz_question_id = qc.quiz_question_id AND q.cat_ques_id = cq.cat_ques_id LIMIT 10";

$questions_query_result = mysqli_query($con, $questions_query) or die("error loading questions");

$questions_results = array();

encode_result($questions_query_result);

function encode_result($result)
{
    //$response = array();
    $questions = array();
    //$choices = array();
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        //$response[] = $r;
        //$questions = array('question' => $r[0]);
        $questions[] = $r['question'];
        $questions[] = $r[4];
        $choices[] = array('quiz_choice_id' => $r[1], 'choice' => $r[2], 'is_correct_choice' => $r[3]);
        $questions[] = $choices;


        //array_push($questions,  $questions['question']);
        //array_push($questions_results, $questions);
    }
    echo json_encode(array('questions'=>$questions));
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

The design of the database is this:
[image]

I can't find a way to make it work because from the database `quiz_choice_id,choice, is_correct_choice` are in a different table but I combined all into one table as you can see in my SQL statement `$questions_query`. Please let me know how can I fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your output is not valid json if we include the question ( outside of the json )

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix May I know what you mean? I didn't quite get it. Thanks.

Comment: You cant have text floating outside the json data.  See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the json to look like this?

```
 [ {
  "question" : "What is the approximate number of islands that comprise the Philippines?",
  "category"    : "Philippine Geography",
  "choices" : [  
         {  
            "quiz_choice_id":"5",
            "choice":"7000",
            "is_correct_choice":"1"
         },
         {  
            "quiz_choice_id":"6",
            "choice":"6000",
            "is_correct_choice":"0"
         },
         {  
            "quiz_choice_id":"7",
            "choice":"8000",
            "is_correct_choice":"0"
         },
         {  
            "quiz_choice_id":"8",
            "choice":"9000",
            "is_correct_choice":"0"
         }
      ]
  },{
    ..... // next question
 }]
```

You'll have to do something like this, but I have no idea what the results of the query is.

```
    $questions = array();
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $key = $r['quiz_question_id']; // you need a key here that is unique to the question, so i think this will do looking at the schema you posted, this will group them in that segment of the array.
        if( !isset( $questions[$key] ) ){
            //if we never had this question, create the top level in the results
            $questions[$key] = array(
                'question' => $r['question'],
                'category'    => $r['category'],
                'choices'  => array()
            );
        }
        //add in the choices for this question
        //on the next iteration, the key is the same so we only do this part
        //and append that rows choices to the previous data using $key to match the question
        $questions[$key]['choices'][] = array('quiz_choice_id' => $r['quiz_choice_id'], 'choice' => $r['choice'], 'is_correct_choice' => $r['is_correct_choice']);
    }
```

Make sure to add `quiz_question_id` to your query if this is the questions id, unique identifier.  Essentially this will group them together, as this will be the same for each row with that question's choices.

I added string keys to the output, I wouldn't mix using string keys and numbered index.  I hope I mapped them out right.

Also I haven't tested this at all, so sorry if there are any syntax errors.

Comment: Yes exactly so what should I do.

Comment: Your getting multiple rows with the question in it right, can you put the query your using. And the schema of the table used would be helpful. you need a key for the level with the question in it. so you can stack them up.

Comment: @ArtisitixPhoenix The query is in the variable called $question_query in the code above. About the schema, I don't know about that but I could show you an ERD if that's ok with you.

Comment: I have updated and upload the design for it. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I see now, not used to looking at joins without the word JOIN in the sql.   In any case my answer should get you close.

Comment: Yeah I think so but I will make this as a solution when I get back to it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I thought in my head,   So you should be getting multiple rows for the same question but with different choices.

Comment: ArisiticPhoenix Yes it does output multiple rows for the same question but different choices.

Comment: Ok, then I pictured it right.  What I put above for the answer should be fairly close to what you need.